# Each loop variables into background images, hiding the key?

Tags: jquery, loops, variables, background-image, each

The answer to this is maybe really simple so go easy on me, I've only just started jQuery in the past month.

Put together an `each` loop to go through images in a slider, href'ing them to the key. Code looks something like this:

```js
var images = [{key:'1', img:'photo1.jpg'},{key:'2', img:'photo2.jpg'},
    {key:'3', img:'photo3.jpg'},{key:'4', img:'photo4.jpg'}]; 

var buttons = $("<~ul id='index_buttons' />");
$.each(images, function(imgIndex, imgData) {
    $(buttons).append($("<~li><~a href='" + imgData.img + "'>" + imgData.key + "<~/a><~/li>"));
```

The problem is that I want to place a menu on top of the slider that it generates. This can be done by changing all the images to styled `"background-image:"`. So I tried:

```js
$(buttons).append($("<~li><~a style=\"background-image:" +  imgData.img 
  + "\"href='"  + imgData.key + "'>""<~/a><~/li>"));
```

With little success.

As well as this, the buttons rely on the key for there to be a link. The key I've replaced for images, but how do you hide/ remove the key without breaking the link?

Thanks :)